# Average number of comparisons searching a list of size n?

Tags: algorithm, search, comparison

so this is a homework question for one of my algorithms classes. I am having a tough time grasping the whole complexity/running time stuff so any answers and explanations would be appreciated!

Consider a randomly generated list of size n.
(a) If the list is stored in random order, what is the expected (average) number of comparisons we will make over a sequence of M searches if αn of these searches are successful,i.e., we are searching for an item that is on the list.
(b) What is the expected average number of searches if the items are stored in order (so
that we can use a more efficient search strategy, such as bisection search).

I feel as though the answer to the first one would be n/2 or something but not sure how to figure in the α part.

Comment: Never write any question saying it is a homework. People here will presume that you are asking for help without trying. By the way, I don't see any of your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are randomly placed in the list, and all of the M searches result in you finding the item, then the expected number of comparisons would be n/2 per search.

Think of it this way. The item you're looking for has a 50% chance to be in the front half of the list, and a 50% chance of being in the back half of the list. If it's in the back half of the list, then there's a 50% chance it'll be in the first half of that sub-list, and a 50% chance it'll be in the second half of that 50%. Same kind of thing if the item is in the first half of the list.

If you do n unique searches (one for each item in the list), the total number of comparisons would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + n. That works out to `n*(n+1)/2` comparisons. Divide that by n and you get `(n+1)/2`.

If you do M random searches, then *on average* you'll get very similar results. The number of searches that take fewer than n/2 comparisons will approximately balance the number that take more than n/2 comparisons.

Now, if some of the searches are unsuccessful, they take n comparisons. So the average becomes more like:

```
(successful*n/2 + unsuccessful*n)/M
```

Comment: Ah ok I could not think of how to factor in the successful and unsuccessful concept, but seeing your math now it makes complete sense, thanks

Comment: I'm sure this is the answer the question-setter expects, but how can you assume that the location of an item being searched for is equally likely to be at any index in the array? At best the question is poorly worded, and missing some assumptions (for example, that all the array items are unique, and that "random order" means every permutation is equally likely, and that the searches are chosen before the array is permuted).

Comment: @PaulHankin: Yes, the question is poorly worded and lacking in detail. I made a bunch of assumptions about the nature of the data based on similar problems I've encountered in the past.